# ASP.NET MVC application when deployed to IIS 7 in integrated mode using NHibernate data will not load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, deployment, iis-7

We have built an ASP.NET MVC application which utilizes [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html), the [MVCContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) version of [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/), and an [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) as outlined by Jeffery Palermo in [ASP.NET MVC in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988622). This application works well when running locally from Visual Studio 2008.

The *Index* action on our *Home* controller loads a view which immediately pulls data from the database utilizing the tools as outlined above. When running on IIS 6 or in Classic Mode on IIS 7 this section of the page loads data. Of course in both of these modes [404 File Not Found](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) errors abound. Unfortunately, when running under IIS 7 Integrated mode no data loads and a simple error message *Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request* is displayed where the data should be rendered. Other page elements like CSS and images are loaded. Is there an IIS 7 setting we have missed? Is there something I should be looking for in the web.config?

**Edit**

Changed the `customErrors mode` setting in the web.config to `off`. Not sure if this is an ASP.NET MVC or IIS 7 thing but am now seeing a standard error screen on the pages that used to display the sorry error message. I am getting an unhandled exception of ***NullReferenceException***: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Looking at the stack this appears to be occurring when trying to get data. What would be the difference between IIS 7 Classic Mode / IIS 6 and IIS 7 Integrated mode that would cause this issue?

**Edit 2**

After some Googling this morning came across a post [MVC + Sharp + IIS7 + NHibernate](http://scottsdalewebstudio.com/blog/mvc/mvc-sharp-iis7-nhibernate/) which seems like it would solve the problem. The post is from June '09 has something changed in the time since then that I don't have to drop back to classic mode?

Comment: On a side note, it would be nice to remove the associate tag from the Amazon link, or at least disclose the fact.

Comment: @Franci Stack Overflow adds the associate link not me. Details on why here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links and here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/.

Comment: Ah, I missed that they started doing this.

Comment: Would be helpful to see code and the error message.

Comment: Yeah, disclose the error message and the IIS setup. Otherwise, the culprit could be whatever.

Comment: @bzlm I've updated the post to include the error message. What sort of IIS configuration information would be helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking about what was going on and realizing that issue probably had something to do with NHibernate I refined some of my Google searches and found a post [HttpModule and HttpHandler sections in IIS 7 web.config files](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/168221.aspx). This reminded me that NHibernate requires an `httpModules` entry.

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="StartupModule" type="Infrastructure.NHibernateModule,
         Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Because of the way that IIS 7 in integrated mode works I had to add the following to the `modules` section of `system.webServer`.

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="StartupModule" type="Infrastructure.NHibernateModule,
         Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Because I needed to have both the modules work in both `system.web` and `system.webServer` I added the `validation` section to the `system.webServer`.

Comment: @MikeChristensen glad it was of use! Interestingly, it's gotten several up votes lately after laying dormant for years. ;)